# Compute weighted cumulative sum for all pair of start point / end point in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, data-science

I have a numpy array `signal` and I try to compute the following value:

```py
C = (signal[t_begin:t_end + 1] * (np.arange(t_end - t_begin + 1) + 1)).sum()
```

For all pairs `t_begin`, `t_end` such that 0 <= `t_begin` <= `t_end` < `len(signal)` without using a `for` loop.

I tried to generate all possible `t_begin`, `t_end` couple and use them as indices in signal in the following way:

```py
t_begin_indices, t_end_indices = np.meshgrid(np.arange(2, n + 1), np.arange(2, n + 1), indexing='ij')
s = t_end_indices - t_begin_indices + 1
valid_mask = s > 0
s_valid = s[valid_mask]
C = signal[t_begin_indices[valid_mask]:t_end_indices[valid_mask]+1] * ((np.arange(s_valid) + 1)[:, np.newaxis])
```

But I get the following error: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: so have you identified what part of that code produced the error?  What is it that requires the scalar index?

Comment: I just wrote an answer for someone elese who was getting the `TypeError`. 
 It may help you understand your problem 
 (arrays can't be used in `slices`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75773619/what-is-a-vectorized-way-to-perform-a-sliding-window/75776868#75776868

Answer (score 0):

You use np.add.reduceat
Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html

The reason why I suggested this because you are encountering t_begin_indices and t_end_indices are two-dimensional arrays, but the slicing operation signal[t_begin_indices[valid_mask]:t_end_indices[valid_mask]+1] is expecting a one-dimensional array of indices and np.add.reduceat helps perform the sum in a vectorized manner.

Try the below:

```
t_begin_indices = np.arange(n-1)
t_end_indices = np.arange(1, n)
s = t_end_indices - t_begin_indices + 1
C = np.add.reduceat(signal[t_begin_indices] * (s + 1), t_end_indices)
```